# How to use JavaScript language in unity?

Tags: unity, javascript

I recently read somewhere that the unity engine supports JavaScript language but I have a question.
How to use JavaScript language in unity engine?

Comment: They have started to unsupport UnityScript (they never used true JS but rather psuedo JS called UnityScript.) . You can still use UnityScript scripts in the code however by simply dragging the script files into your script folder as a workaround. Read this: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your information is out of date. Unity used to support Javascript, via a custom Javascript variant language called UnityScript. It also used to have a language called Boo. Support for both has been discontinued. C# is now the only language that Unity uses for scripts. By default, this is 3.5 version of C#, but 4.6 is an option you can switch to via the Player Settings option screen.

Comment: More information about the UnityScript deprecation process can be found in the Unity blog article [UnityScript’s long ride off into the sunset](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/)